# How to modify PHP array keys

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I have some basic data coming from a csv upload, the table is formatted like so:

| Cost 1 | Cost 2 | Cost 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 12 | 5 |
| 1 | 13 | 9 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 |

The data saves to the database and using array_chunk I have an array that looks like this (I will need to loop through these later)

```
array(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [Cost 1] => 5
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [Cost 2] => 12
      )
  [2] => Array
      (
          [Cost 3] => 3
      )
   )
```

I want to modify the array to read the keys as values instead, so the final array would look like this with the column title saving in every instance:

```
array(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [cost] => Cost 1
          [demand] => 5
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [cost] => Cost 2
          [demand] => 12
      )
  [2] => Array
      (
          [cost] => Cost 3
          [demand] => 3
      )
   )
```

I know I can use array_keys and array_values to target each, but can't quite get my head around how I'd use that to create the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script work for you 
I first iterate the array with foreach and then in each element use the `array_keys` and `array_values` for give the keys and values and because that is just one row in the element I use the `[0]`

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [
        "Cost 1" => 5
    ],
    [
        "Cost 2" => 12
    ],
    [
        "Cost 3" => 3
    ],
];

$formattedArray = [];
foreach($array as $element) {
    $formattedArray[] = [
        "cost" => array_keys($element)[0],
        "demand" => array_values($element)[0],
    ];
}

print_r($formattedArray);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Cost 1
            [demand] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Cost 2
            [demand] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Cost 3
            [demand] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newCostArray=[];
foreach($costArray as $index => $carr) {
  $newCostArray[$index]=[];
  foreach($carr as $key => $val) {
     echo "$key = $val<br>";
     $newCostArray[$index]['cost']=$key;
     $newCostArray[$index]['demand']=$val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding the link to your answer as a comment, add a line of text "As suggested **here** we can do something like". It improves the readability of your question and can improve the answers performance (votes).

Comment: I created that link though  but thanks alot I'll keep that in mind @Oliver 